# group by clause does't show all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my project I have used a select query with group by clause, when I execute it instead of showing 9 records,it's shown 8 records! one records doesn't shown.
Here is my code

```
  select year(RegisterDate),Volume,Issue,CategoryId   
  from Articles   
  where     CategoryId=14   
  Group by    year(RegisterDate),Volume,Issue,CategoryId
```

The first picture is the Main data and the second picture is result. As you see a record doesn't shown
[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Comment: Can you please share your sample data and indicate what value you perceive to be missing?

Comment: You have two records with the same value of the group by columns.  In addition, you don't seem to understand `group by`, because you are using aggregation functions on `group by` keys.

Comment: 12 test1  14 Volume1 Issue3 10/27/2015 NULL author1 abs1
13 test2  14 Volume1 Issue3 11/4/2015        NULL        author2 abs2           the second  one doesn't shown

Comment: Don't just jam some data in comment.  Show what is in the table and what results you desire IN the question.

Comment: If you include a `count(*)` you'll better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I see you posted data
As I stated before group by will only return unique rows
You only have 8 unique 
year(RegisterDate), Volume, Issue, CategoryId
I think you want a simple select

```
select year(RegisterDate), CategoryId, Volume, Issue
from Articles
where CategoryId = 14
```

You have an aggregate in the group by
Are you sure you want to do that?
Try

```
select year(RegisterDate), CategoryId, max(Volume), max(Issue)
from Articles
where CategoryId = 14
Group by year(RegisterDate), CategoryId
```

You will get unique year(RegisterDate), CategoryId only with that group by

Comment: I want to show my data based on three columns group by(year,Volume,Issue)

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the max(volume) and max(issue).  It is really strange to have a column in the group by to aggregated.   I suggest you post data and the results you desire as you don't seem to understand group by.

Comment: I'v edited my question with adding pictures and editting query

Answer (score 0):

Note in the sample data that rows with ids 12 and 13 share the very same aggregation condition (`year(RegisterDate),Volume,Issue,CategoryId`). Hence these two rows will be grouped in a single group, as you requested in the query. All others have different values combinations and will form their own groups.

Answer (score 0):

You have 'Issue3' twice in your column 'Issue', which correspond to 'Volume1', and this is why you miss a row when you do your grouping. If you want to use a 'GROUP BY' statement in your query, then your 8 rows back as result are correct, but if you want to have 9 rows back as result, you should not use a 'GROUP BY' statement in your query. I would suggest using something like this:

```
SELECT Year(RegisterDate) 'Year', Volume, Issue
FROM Articles
WHERE CategoryId = 14
  AND Title >= 'Article1' AND Title <= 'Article9'
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks I solved it by adding another column to my query

```
select year(RegisterDate),Volume,Issue,CategoryId,Title from Articles where CategoryId=14 Group by  year(RegisterDate),Volume,Issue,CategoryId,Title
```